# No effect of umask and chmod on mounted drives

Tags: linux, chmod, umask

The windows drives are mounted at boot-time using [pysdm](http://pysdm.sourceforge.net/). The setting were

`nls=iso8859-1,users,umask=002,sync,user,dirsync,uid=mtk`

When I try to change the permission of files using chmod, I don't see any update in the permissions. Chmod quietly returns the prompt. Also the permission of created files must have been 755 instead of 775. Here is the output of terminal.

```
mtk@mtk-laptop$ umask
0022
mtk@mtk-laptop$ touch abc.txt
mtk@mtk-laptop$ ls -l abc.txt 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mtk root 0 May 14 00:00 abc.txt*
mtk@mtk-laptop$ chmod ugo-x abc.txt 
mtk@mtk-laptop$ ls -l abc.txt 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mtk root 0 May 14 00:00 abc.txt*
mtk@mtk-laptop$
```

Does anyone know what is the issue behind this?

I am using ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: The filesystem is NTFS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unix permissions don't apply to and can't be mapped to Windows permissions, so `chmod` is necessarily a no-op.  (FAT doesn't have permissions at that granularity, and NTFS permissions are stored not by username or numeric ID but by a UUID that Linux has no access to.)  The permissions you see are manufactured by the `umask=002` part of the mount options.

Comment: Ok, I get the point. But in that case 'chmod' or 'umask' should have returned some message :). Thanks for the response.

Comment: `umask` won't return any message; it changes a setting associated with your process, it doesn't affect any files anywhere, and its runtime action is to silently modify an `open(..., O_CREAT)`, with no way for anything to report an error specific to that modifiction.  Whether `chmod` should report an error is arguable; the Linux developers decided it should not, since otherwise many programs would throw pointless errors when applied to files in Windows filesystems.