# Unable to change file permissions

Tags: ubuntu, chmod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No effect of umask and chmod on mounted drives](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38583/no-effect-of-umask-and-chmod-on-mounted-drives)

I am not able to change file permissions using `chmod` from the user who owns the file as well as from root. I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

The directory is located on my windows partition, but I have never had the same problem earlier.

Any hints?

Comment: What is the approach you're using that is not working for you?

Comment: Can you give us (a lot) more info describing your problem? FileSystem of the partition, `ls -l` on the file, the error message you get, both from user and from root, ...

Comment: Possible duplicate [No effect of umask and chmod on mounted drives](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38583/17265).

Answer (score 0):

If the directory is located on your Windows partition, it means the partition is in NTFS. NTFS does not support permissions and thus `chown`/`chmod` won't work for files and directories in that partition. Actually I'd be surprised if you said it ever worked before.